# Can you help me identify this literary term?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am trying to write an essay based on a book I read in class where there was a guy (Okonkwo) who hated his lazy father, so he became hard working and furious at anyone who wasn't due to his father's nature. Then, his son hated his ways, so Okonkwo's son vowed to be accepting of others due to how much he hated his father's ways.

I am about 90% sure that I have heard a term for this type of repeated action (I don't mean a motif), but I can't get my finger on it. Any response would be helpful.

Also, if it matters, the book is *Things Fall Apart* by Chinua Achebe.

Answer (score 1):

"Leitmotif" works best; "thematic patterning" is perhaps another.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Answers on Stack Exchange communities are intended to provide some justification for why they are correct. Dictionary entries, logical argument, examples of usage, etc all help. You can use the [edit] link to add some to your answer.